# Downloading image from API to a specific directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I aim to create a program in ReactJS that works Offline. That is, the program will have the information stored locally and only when it is necessary to update, will be connected to the internet and download it using an API.

At this point, I chose to store the information coming from the API in LocalStorage.

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('api.url')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => localStorage.setItem('fromAPI',JSON.stringify(data)))
  }
```

My question is: the API in question will have photos, and it will be necessary to download these photos to store them locally. How can I store them locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean store them locally?

Your web app cannot access user's hard drive as it pleases. You can download resources with download prompt, or simply to user's set download folder, but to reuse them, you'd need the user to give you upload access to them (with `input[type=file]`). I guess this is not what you're looking for.

Alternatively, you can store files within `localStorage`, presumably base64-encoded. (Altho I think utf16 might work as well.) Just beware of localStorage's size limitation, around 5 - 10 MB depending on browser.

Comment: My goal isn't to create a web app online. I intend to create something like a [digital frame photo](https://aluratek.com/eight-inch-digital-photo-frame)), in which some information (day, ppl) will be stored in local storage. For each photo, the API returns a url (from the API itself) with the photo:
```
"imgs": [
   {
      "id": 167,
       "listImg": "api.url/file/img-name.jpg"
}]
```

My goal is to download the photos to the directory of the React App whenever I connect to the internet, so that when I disconnect the photos they will remain saved and the program will show them.

Comment: Then try something like this: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/ Just beware the storage limit.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand if you want to save the image URL?

If you don't - you can save the base64 of the image,
read about how to convert the image to base64.
Here is a nice package you can use:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-base64

Comment: My goal isn't to create a web app online. I intend to create something like a [digital frame photo](https://aluratek.com/eight-inch-digital-photo-frame)), in which some information (day, ppl) will be stored in local storage. For each photo, the API returns a url (from the API itself) with the photo:
```
"imgs": [
   {
      "id": 167,
       "listImg": "api.url/file/img-name.jpg"
}]
```

My goal is to download the photos to the directory of the React App whenever I connect to the internet, so that when I disconnect the photos they will remain saved and the program will show them.